# Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them workaround

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, next.js

I am using the [reactjs popup](https://react-popup.elazizi.com/react-modal/) library and I have implemented the code below:

```js
<Popup trigger={<a href="javascript:void(0)">bobby</a>} modal>
    <button className="close" onClick={close}>
        &times;
    </button>
</Popup>
```

I am unable to close out the popup with the button because of this error. Is there any workaround/technology that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as the children to the `Popup` component.

```js
<Popup trigger={<a href="javascript:void(0)">bobby</a>} modal>
    {(close) => (
        <button className="close" onClick={close}>
            &times;
        </button>
    )}
</Popup>
```